# Azure Process terminates when javascript function is changed

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm running the default anonymous azure function javascript function, when I make a change to it (even a space) the process quits rather suddenly, the terminal closes with the following output:

> [12/3/2018 5:41:20 PM] node process with Id=96216 started [12/3/2018
>   5:41:20 PM] Generating 2 job function(s) [12/3/2018 5:41:20 PM] Found
>   the following functions: [12/3/2018 5:41:20 PM]
>   Host.Functions.HelloWorld [12/3/2018 5:41:20 PM] Host.Functions.Test
>   [12/3/2018 5:41:20 PM] [12/3/2018 5:41:20 PM] Host initialized (89ms)
>   [12/3/2018 5:41:20 PM] Host started (92ms) [12/3/2018 5:41:20 PM] Job
>   host started [12/3/2018 5:41:20 PM] Stopping JobHost [12/3/2018
>   5:41:20 PM] Job host stopped [12/3/2018 5:41:20 PM] Host restarted.
>   [12/3/2018 5:41:21 PM] Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:5858 failed:
>   address already in use [12/3/2018 5:41:21 PM] Language Worker Process
>   exited.

Not sure what's going on.

One thing to note, I have to change the code with the function in a breakpoint otherwise the process and terminal both terminate before I can select the code output.

Comment: This should be related to fact/[issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3415) the language workers initialized inside ScriptHost, thus any edit on the file cause it to restart.

Comment: @Curios is right.